# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'loader'. Expected a ':' following the property name 'class'

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to namespace my classes, but get the following errors. How do you add a class to an object literal?

```
Helpers = window.Helpers || {};
Helpers.Bootstrap = Helpers.Bootstrap || {};

Helpers.Bootstrap.Spinner = {
  class loader {

    constructor(element = '.spinner-border') {
      this.element = $(this)
    }

    show() {
      this.element.css("display", "block");

    }

    hide() {
      this.element.css("display", "none");
    }
  },
  class button {

    constructor(element = '.btn_spinner') {
      this.element  = $(this);
      this.html     = $(this).html();
    }

    show() {
      $(this).prop("disabled", true);
      $(this).html(
        `<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>Loading...`
      );
    }

    hide() {
      this.element.prop("disabled", false);
      this.element.html(this.html);
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {   
  const SpinnerBtn = new Helpers.Bootstrap.spinner.button();
});
```

I tried below to simplify the issue.

```
Helpers = window.Helpers || {};
Helpers.Bootstrap = Helpers.Bootstrap || {};

Helpers.Bootstrap.Spinner = {
  Loader: class Loader {
     }
  },
  Button : class Button {
   }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {   
  const SpinnerBtn = new Helpers.Bootstrap.Spinner.Button();
});
```

Error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Loader'. Expected a ':' following
>   the property name 'class'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Helpers.Bootstrap.Spinner = {
  class loader {
```

`Helpers.Bootstrap.Spinner` is an object. That's what that `{` means on that first line.

You can't put a class definition inside of an object. The parser thinks `class` is a property name, and thus should have a colon after it.

I don't know what you're trying to do so I can't fix this for you, but just don't do that? Also class names should be `Capitalized`.

---

Example w/ syntax fixed:

```js
const Helpers = window.Helpers || {};
Helpers.Bootstrap = Helpers.Bootstrap || {};

Helpers.Bootstrap.Spinner = {
  Loader: class Loader {},
  Button: class Button {},
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  const spinnerBtn = new Helpers.Bootstrap.Spinner.Button();
  console.log(spinnerBtn.constructor.name);
});
```

Comment: I am trying to namespace the class Loader and namespace the class Button

Comment: Ah... then Rami has the solution. I'd still capitalize it as `loader: class Loader {...}` to help distinguish the property name from the class name. You can technically drop the class name altogether, but it can be nice for debugging.

Comment: please see update. would also appreciate reopening question. thanks

Comment: @user2012677 You had some mismatched braces. FTFY

Comment: Thank you, Rami had part of solution but you fixed syntax error.  Wish I could accept both answers

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add two fields to an object without keys

```
Helpers.Bootstrap.Spinner = {
    loader: class loader {...}
    button: class button {...}
}
```

Comment: Added Loader: and Button:, but got `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'context.createDocumentFragment')`, and should I have a comma after {...}?

Comment: `Helpers.Bootstrap.spinner.button();` in this call `spinner` and `button` should have the same case as you defined them! `Spinner` and `Button`